# Python Thread Breaking Terminal

Tags: python, linux

Hello minds of stackoverflow,

I've run into a perplexing bug.  I have a python script that creates a new thread that ssh's into a remote machine and starts a process.  However, this process does not return on its own (and I want it to keep running throughout the duration of my script).  In order to force the thread to return, at the end of my script I ssh into the machine again and kill -9 the process.  This is working well, expect for the fact that it breaks the terminal.

To start the thread I run the following code:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=run_vUE_rfal, args=(vAP.IP, vUE.IP))
t.start()
```

The function run_vUE_rfal is as follows:

```
cmd = "sudo ssh -ti ~/.ssh/my_key.pem user@%s 'sudo /opt/company_name/rfal/bin/vUE-rfal -l 3 -m -d %s -i %s'" % (vUE_IP, vAP_IP, vUE_IP)
output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
return
```

It seems when the command is run, it somehow breaks my terminal.  It is broken in that instead of creating a new line for each print, it appends the WIDTH of my terminal in whitespace to the end of each line and prints it as seemingly one long string. Also, I am unable to see my keyboard input to that terminal, but it still successfully read. My terminal looks something like this:

```
normal formatted output
normal formatted output
running vUE-rfal
print1
      print2
            print3_extra_long
                             print4
```

If I replace the body of the run_vUE_rfal function with some simple prints, the terminal does not break.  I have many other ssh's and telnets in this script that work fine.  However, this is the only one I'm running in a separate thread as it is the only one that does not return.  I need to maintain the ability to close the process of the remote machine when my script is finished.

Any explanations to the cause and idea for a fix are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the multi-threading. What is `commands.getstatusoutput`? What happens if you replace the actual command with something benign, such as `ls`?

Comment: Im very sure you're correct.  Replacing the program with a simple 'ls' does not break my terminal.  I have a feeling the issue is rooted in the fact that the process I am invoking though ssh does not return, so the thread hangs at commands.getstatusoutput until I ssh into the machine again and kill the process.  To answer your question, commands is a standard python module I'm using. It runs the command on shell and returns the output and return code.

Comment: use `subprocess` instead of `commands` . You are spawning a process, so use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`

Comment: Thank @NizamMohamed. I've implemented your suggested changes but don't see any difference in the output.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if I redirect the script output to log, the formatting of the log is correct. However, my terminal still gets broken. What gives!?

And like @deets helped me show, I can run 'ls' or 'echo' commands perfectly fine, but running the script I need to seems to break it.

Comment: It sounds like you're killing a process that sets some terminal mode flags that it would normally unset before exiting. Sending SIGKILL to the process won't give it a chance to "clean up" after itself. Have you tried killing it with SIGTERM or something else instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the process you control is changing terminal settings. These are *bypassing* stderr and stdout - for good reasons. E.g. ssh itself needs this to ask users for passwords even when it's output is being redirected.

A way to solve this could be to use the python-module `pexpect` (it's a 3rd-party library) to launch your process, as it will create its' own fake-tty you don't care about.

BTW, to "repair" your terminal, use the `reset` command. As you already noticed, you can enter commands. `reset` will set the terminal to default settings.

Comment: Thanks @deets. Got it working the way I wanted. The key was pexpect, though I had to do some finagling to get that to work correctly.